# Calculate % of textbox filled in

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar

I am working on a javafx project in which I'm providing a textbox to be filled in.I want to calculate % of textbox filled in..say for eg 100 characters is a limit and 50 are filled in so 50 should be the % value but it should change automatically as i keep typing .I don't know exactly how to do that (specially the Automatic thing). I want to show that % value on progressbar like this :
(Ignore buttons)

[image]
Need help! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define yourself a `DoubleBinding` which is bound to the `textProperty` and on each change revaluates it's value.

```
final double max = 100;
TextField text = new TextField();
DoubleBinding percentage = new DoubleBinding() {
    {
        super.bind(text.textProperty());
    }
    @Override
    protected double computeValue() {
        return text.getText().length() / max;
    }
};
```

In the static initializer block of the `DoubleBinding` you bind the `textProperty` of your `TextField`. This will cause the reevaluation of the binding through the `computeValue` method. Then you can bind it to the `textProperty` of a `Label`:

```
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.textProperty().bind(percentage.asString());
```

Of course you can also bind it to other controls than a `Label` like a `ProgressBar` or `ProgressIndicator`:

```
ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
bar.progressProperty().bind(percentage);
ProgressIndicator indicator = new ProgressIndicator();
indicator.progressProperty().bind(percentage);
```

This binding then can be used to display the percentage already filled in. You might also take a look at this [documentation by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#sthref8). The type of this binding is a low-level binding.

Comment: Thanx @hotzst ..can u please elaborate a bit explanation of how it can help.i'm not getting documentation

Comment: @minigeek added some more explanation as well as several examples how to use the binding.

Comment: Tysm @hotzst ...gr8